# How to set new job each time with different interval

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm pretty new to Quartz and I've come a cross the following requirement:

I need to create a scheduler that schedules single job that each time it ends it rescheduled *but* with calculated interval time.

For example:
1. Start job that ends after 15minutes, then when finished reschedule it to end after 1Hour, when finished reschedule it to end after 45 minutes...and so on...

The point is that when job finishes I dynamically calculate the next interval and need to fire the event again.

How to accomplish that with Quartz?

Thanks.

Comment: "when finished reschedule it to end after 1Hour" - did you mean "end after" or "start after" ?

Comment: are you asking about recursive scheduling? i.e. could your job schedule itself to be executed in 1h or so in the last step of it's execution.

Comment: it should reschedule itself at the end of the dynamic interval.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you can trigger it explicitly for the first time, something like

```
scheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);
scheduler.triggerJob(jobName, groupName); //(1)
```

and code the job class such a way that after its main work is done, calculate the next trigger time and schedule it before job exits. Something like

```
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger); //(2)
```

Note that the the job trigger in code snippet (1) removes the job after its done. That means you will have to schedule it, in (2), as if its a new job as far as scheduler is concerned.